# GCC plugin adding a pass to introduce new keyword

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I have just started exploring into the world of GCC plugins API and I'm trying to extend GCC for the following example.

```
class Foo { ... };

Foo* f = __construct Foo(); // __construct is meant to be a new keyword
```

Ideally, I'd like the plugin to simply replace `__construct` with something like `new (foo_class_info)`, so you'll end up with

```
Foo* f = new (foo_class_info) Foo();
```

where `foo_class_info` has been made available via `PLUGIN_FINISH_TYPE` callback (i.e. __construct cannot be replaced at the preprocessor pass).

What would be the right / easiest way to achieve this? I don't even mind combining some user-land template codes with the plugin.

Would adding a new pass be the way to go? If so, I could really use some pointers.

Comment: What is the point of this keyword? Your reasoning behind needing it?

Comment: @Pubby so that I could pass some info that I could only get via PLUGIN_FINISH_TYPE callback for Foo to an overloaded new.

Comment: My initial instinct is that you're over-complicating your potential implementation, but the question doesn't say what you're *really* trying to solve with this mechanism. With more details we might be able to provide a language solution that doesn't tie you to a specific compiler.

Comment: @MarkB I'm actually just learning how to write a GCC plugin that extends the language via a custom keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins fundamentally cannot change the syntax.

The most you can do is add a new pragma, attribute, or builtin, then do something with that in a later pass.